# Entanglement and isomorphism of linear spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quantum-computation

Here is something that I do not understand.

According the concept of entanglement, the quantum state

$$| \psi \rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(| 0 \rangle+| 3 \rangle)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(| 00 \rangle+| 11 \rangle)$$

which is the quantum state of two qubits (in a two atom system), cannot be written as a tensor product of quantum states of two separate qubits. More specifically

$$| \psi \rangle\neq (\alpha_0|0\rangle +\alpha_1|1\rangle)\otimes (\beta_0|0\rangle +\beta_1|1\rangle)$$

for all possible $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_0,\beta_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, I have noticed that

$$\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$$

which means that there should be a one-to-one mapping between them.
So, I expect $(\alpha_0|0\rangle +\alpha_1|1\rangle)\otimes (\beta_0|0\rangle +\beta_1|1\rangle)$ to produce $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(| 0 \rangle+| 3 \rangle)$, as a member of $\mathbb{R}^4$, for some coefficients $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_0,\beta_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. But it is not possible.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any hints or answers.

Comment: Granted I didn't understand all the physics gobbledygook, when you factor out $(\alpha_0|0\rangle +\alpha_1|1\rangle)\otimes (\beta_0|0\rangle +\beta_1|1\rangle)$, and try to get the cross terms (i.e. $|0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle$ and $|1\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$) to drop out, you'll force too many coefficients to be zero.

Comment: The use of $|3\rangle$ is strange here. The meaning of the label is in the individual digits, not the number you can produce by interpreting them as a binary numeral. And this is not a setting where there is any compelling reason to want to compress the label.

Comment: @Hurkyl, in the literature, related to quantum computation, this notation is usually used. So, instead of $|11 \rangle$, one writes $|3 \rangle$, to compress a bit.

Comment: @Aweygan, sorry for the unfamiliar terms, from physics. I thought these concepts are also taught in mathematics. I understood my mistake. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget that the tensor product of spaces consists of linear combinations of pure tensors.

$$|00 \rangle + |11 \rangle = |0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle + |1\rangle \otimes |1\rangle$$

Comment: Thank you. You pointed out a notion that I did not know. Now I know what to look for.